# Ошибка создания проекта Django с использованием docker-compose run

Tags: linux, django, docker, docker-compose

Пользуясь инструкцией с docs.docker.com, ввожу:

```
sudo docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample
```

для создания проекта Django.
Выдает ошибку:

```
 ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because 
 you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or 
 "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and 
 place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

Файл docker-compose.yml (создан по той же инструкции):

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Версия linux: 20.04.1.
Версия docker: 20.10.3.
Версия docker-compose: 1.25.0.
Версия Python: 3.8.5.

Comment: Попробуйте версию в докер компоузе изменить на 3.8

Comment: Я попробовал-не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose` версии 1.25.0 поддерживает спецификации до версии `3.7` включительно. Обновите `docker-compose` или уменьшите версию в `docker-compose.yml`.